# How to assign one image to all image sources of buttons

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am using WPF-Xaml I made interface in which user selects image and save it in database, then this saved image assigned to buttons `ImageSource` and similarly to all other Navigation Panel items, etc.

*Problem is that*: i have to retrieve image every time from database, Is there any other possibility to save image without connectivity to database i mean `Application Settings` ?

*i am not using MVVM*

Comment: So basically you want your image to be persisted to some place other than memory?

Comment: @GETah Yes . can i store this to application settings file in WPF

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in your view model that will hold this image:

```
public class ViewModel{
   public ImageSource SharedImage{get;set;}
}
```

Then bind your controls that need to show this image to this property. This way the image is set once and used my times by other controls that need to access it.

**EDIT**
If you want to cache your file locally in your file system when your application first uses the image you could do the following:

```
public class ViewModel{
   private ImageSource _sharedImage;
   public ImageSource SharedImage{
      get{
         if(_sharedImage== null){
                  // Go load the image from somewhere
         }
         return _sharedImage;
      }
      set{
         if(_sharedImage == null){
              // Store the image contained in value into your local cache
         }
          _sharedImage = value;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: how to cache the file locally?

Comment: just save your file to disk when you first set your property - see my edit

Comment: thank you. but as i told you there is no view model in my application. so can i use this in UserControl. Secondly I am using Devexpress, it provides MVVM, but it's interface does not meet my requirement. i have tried to change it , but as has little knowledge about MVVM so i moved back. Now you make me more confuse to choose my way that where i should have to go. :(